# Calculating Subtotals using rollup in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, rollup

I have a table(#mytable) that contains basic financial info about companies.

```
CREATE TABLE #mytable 
(
        Companyid varchar2(50),
        DataDescription varchar2(100),
        Value DECIMAL(23,6),
        Department varchar2(100),
        CurrencyIS03 varchar2(5),
        DateofData datetime
)

INSERT INTO #mytable (Companyid, DataDescription, Value, Department, CurrencyIS03, DateofData)
    SELECT 
        'A100', 'Revenue', '1000.00', 'Corporate', 'USD', '2014-12-31 00:00:00' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A100','Revenue','2000.00','Banking','USD','2014-12-31 00:00:00'     
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A100','Revenue','2500.00','Corporate','USD','2013-12-31 00:00:00' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A100','Revenue','3000.00','Banking','USD','2013-12-31 00:00:00' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A100','Operating Income','10000.00','Corporate','USD','2014-12-31 00:00:00' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A100','Operating Income','1000.00','Banking','USD','2014-12-31 00:00:00' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A200','Revenue','1100.00','Corporate','USD','2013-12-31 00:00:00' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A200','Revenue','3000.00','Banking','USD','2013-12-31 00:00:00' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A200','Operating Income','5500.00','Corporate','USD','2014-12-31 00:00:00' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A200','Operating Income','10000.00','Banking','USD','2014-12-31 00:00:00'
```

I have to find sub totals based on Companyid, DataDescription, Department, CurrencyIS03, DateofData. I am not sure how to do that. I tried doing the following

```
select 
    Companyid, DataDescription,
    sum(Value) as total,
    Department, CurrencyIS03, DateofData 
from 
    #mytable
group by 
    rollup(CompanyID, Datadescription, Department, CurrencyIS03, DateofData)
```

This is not returning the correct answer.

Below is what I expect.

```
CREATE TABLE #outputtable 
(
        Companyid varchar2(50),
        DataDescription varchar2(100),
        TotalValue DECIMAL(23,6),
        Department varchar2(100),
        CurrencyIS03 varchar2(5),
        DateofData datetime
)

INSERT INTO #outputtable (Companyid, DataDescription, TotalValue, Department, CurrencyIS03, DateofData)
 SELECT 'A100','Revenue','1000.00','Corporate','USD','2014-12-31 00:00:00' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'A100','Revenue','2000.00','Banking','USD','2014-12-31 00:00:00' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'A100','Revenue','3000.00','Total','USD','2014-12-31 00:00:00' UNION ALL

 SELECT 'A100','Revenue','2500.00','Corporate','USD','2013-12-31 00:00:00' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'A100','Revenue','3000.00','Banking','USD','2013-12-31 00:00:00' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'A100','Revenue','5500.00','Total','USD','2013-12-31 00:00:00' UNION ALL

 SELECT 'A100','Operating Income','10000.00','Corporate','USD','2014-12-31 00:00:00' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'A100','Operating Income','1000.00','Banking','USD','2014-12-31 00:00:00' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'A100','Operating Income','11000.00','Total','USD','2014-12-31 00:00:00' UNION ALL

 SELECT 'A200','Revenue','1100.00','Corporate','USD','2013-12-31 00:00:00' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'A200','Revenue','3000.00','Banking','USD','2013-12-31 00:00:00' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'A200','Revenue','4100.00','Total','USD','2013-12-31 00:00:00' UNION ALL

 SELECT 'A200','Operating Income','5500.00','Corporate','USD','2014-12-31 00:00:00' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'A200','Operating Income','10000.00','Banking','USD','2014-12-31 00:00:00' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'A200','Operating Income','15500.00','Total','USD','2014-12-31 00:00:00'
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're only rolling up Department within the grouping so  you just have use `ROLLUP(Department)` and group by the rest normally.

```
SELECT  Companyid,
        DataDescription,
        SUM(Value) AS total,
        COALESCE(Department,'Total') Department,
        CurrencyIS03,
        DateofData
FROM    #mytable
GROUP BY CompanyID,
        Datadescription,
        ROLLUP(Department),
        CurrencyIS03,
        DateofData
ORDER BY CompanyID ASC,
        Datadescription DESC,
        DateofData DESC,
        Department ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to use ROLLUP for this.

I would just do:

```
select * from 
(select Companyid,DataDescription,sum(Value) as Value ,'Total' as Department,CurrencyIS03,DateofData 
 from mytable
 group by CompanyID, Datadescription, CurrencyIS03,DateofData
 union all
 select * from mytable) a
 order by  CompanyID asc, Datadescription desc, DateofData desc, Department asc
```

There is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/77d1b/17/0%20fiddle)